# Как узнать текущее количество потоков в процессе?

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность

Можно ли в текущий момент в коде узнать количество потоков в данном процессе?

```cpp
auto x = get_threads_numbers(); // 1
std::thread(...);
auto y = get_threads_numbers(); // 2
```

Comment: [man proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) В        /proc/pid/status  есть строка `Threads: NN`  (т.е. читаете построчно  /proc/pid/status и sscanf-ом достаете из нужной строки количество потоков)

Comment: @avp а библиотечной функции нет какой-нибудь? Мне для дебага надо - быстро узнать и забыть, а не писать парсер

Comment: А с чего ты взял, что в третьей строке будет 2 (ну или более формально "на 1 больше", чем в первой строке)? Никто тебе таких гарантий не даёт.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov в общем случае может и не 2 быть, это просто пример. Для этого и нужна функция, чтобы узнать сколько точно)

Comment: А в дебаггере нет этой информации?

Comment: @Никита поэтому в скобочках я и уточнил. Немедленная проверка после запуска не имеет смысла, новый поток может успеть попасть в `get_thread_numbers`,  а может и не успеть. Я вообще в принципе не вижу сценариев для такой функции. Даже для отладки.

Comment: @Никита, не знаю таких функций. Если для себя в дебаге, то наверное можно  просто `{char cmd[40]; sprintf(cmd, "grep Threads /proc/%d/status", (int)getpid()); system(cmd);}`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov ещё раз - это просто для демонстрации поведения пример) Это не значит, что она будет вызываться сразу после `std::thread`, это не значит, что потоки создаются именно через `std::thread` и т.п.. Просто пример для понимания. Если поток не успел создаться, значит ответ "1" правильный.

Comment: @avp спасибо в любом случае, попробую это

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, так и делаю сейчас. Но мне надо во многих местах, и не на всякий проход этого места, так что в логе удобнее будет